# Difference in buffer size of inline delegate

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I came to this scenario while using an inline function. Which have raised several question in my mind.
**Example 1:**  (global testDeligate)

```
[Serializable]
class TestClass
{
    Func<int, int> testDeligate = (a) => { a = +10; a = +20; return a; };
    public void testMethod()
    {
        int xx = 10;
        if (xx == 1)
        {
            testDeligate(10);
            return;
        }
        else if (xx == 2)
        {
            testDeligate(20);
            return;
        }
        else if (xx == 3)
        {
            testDeligate(33);
            return;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

**Example 2:**  (Local testDeligate)

```
[Serializable]
class TestClass
{
    public void testMethod()
    {
        Func<int, int> testDeligate = (a) => { a = +10; a = +20; return a; };
        int xx = 10;
        if (xx == 1)
        {
            testDeligate(10);
            return;
        }
        else if (xx == 2)
        {
            testDeligate(20);
            return;
        }
        else if (xx == 3)
        {
            testDeligate(33);
            return;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

While calculating the buffer size of TestClass I am getting different response.

```
    TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    bf.Serialize(ms, testClass);
    var size = ms.Length;
```

**Example 1: size = 1308**
**Example 2: size = 127**
I am not able to figure out the reason why there is difference in buffer size in both the scenario.

Comment: Buffer of serialized class that don't have any member will always be smaller than buffer of serialized class with members

Comment: Binary serialization works by serializing the fields of a class.  Example 2 has no fields.  Example 1 gets beefy not just because of the testDeligate field but it also has to serialize the invisible class that the C# compiler generates to implement the lambda expression.  Note how brittle this is, the serialized data is very apt to become invalid across changes in the code.

Comment: @HansPassant thus it is better to go with the inline function defined inside a method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[After MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/) (emphasis mine):

> Serialization is the process of converting an object into a stream of bytes to store the object or transmit it to memory, a database, or a file. **Its main purpose is to save the state of an object** in order to be able to recreate it when needed.

A member method is obviously not the *state* of an object. It belongs to the type of the object. Every object of this class will have the same method, so there's no point in serializing it. So for your second example the serializer buffers only the metadata to distinguish the type of the serialized object, as it's all there is.

In your first example, however, you have a dynamically assigned delegate member. It's a member field, one that can be easily manipulated within the class. There's nothing stopping you from writing code like

```
class MyClass
{
    Func<int, int> testDeligate = (a) => { a = +10; a = +20; return a; };
    public void MutateMe()
    {
        testDelegate = (a) => 10 * a;
    }
}
```

In this case, the value of the delegate member *is* a part of the state of your object. Thus, the serializer needs to encode all the data that goes into the implementation of the assigned lambda.

Note that if you changed the field to be `static`, you'd get the same size as for example 2. again, as the field would no longer be a part of the state of the object, but a `static` part of the type.

You might wonder what would happen if you changed the field to be `readonly` - the answer is nothing, it would still need to be serialized (so same effect as example 1.), as it still could be dynamically computed at runtime, e.g. in the ctor, so it'd still be a part of the state of the object.